# White Screen of Death

Tags: cache, error

Our users were getting a blank white screen on our homepage yesterday. Inspecting revealed it was just an empty page. All other pages on the site worked fine. I ended up clearing the cache and it resolved the issue.

Any idea why the cache would have been serving an empty page instead of the home page?

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, that's pretty much impossible to say, it could be pretty much anything – though a white screen is often due to PHP errors, in which case you might find a clue in your log files (located at `/craft/storage/runtime/logs` (search for `[error]`). Your web server's error logs might hold some clues as well.